# Whitenoise static file upload not working with DEBUG=False

Tags: python, django

I have a Django web app and I serve static files with Whitenoise. The problem is that I can't upload and get images when `DEBUG=False`. Everything work well with `DEBUG=True` but when I disable it, uploading is not working anymore but retrieving images works.

Here is my whitenoise configuration :

wsgi.py

```
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

and settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'public/static/public/images')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'public/static/'
```

Answer (score 3):

Whitenoise isn't designed for serving media files. It scans the directory at startup, and assumes that the files will not change while the application runs.

See [issue 32](https://github.com/evansd/whitenoise/issues/32) for more information.

Comment: Alright, but the thing is that the media are not stored into the media folder. It seems whitenoise is not able to write into it.

Comment: You haven't shown what error you are getting so we can only guess what the problem is. My guess was that the file is uploaded, but whitenoise does not serve it because it cached the list of files when the server started.

Comment: Yes because I have no error. I checked into my server and the file is not stored, but the image python object is saved into the database models. The error is when I try to retrieve the image, I have a `404 not found`.

Comment: Is it definitely whitenoise that is stopping the media file from being uploaded? If you disable whitenoise but set `DEBUG=False`, does the upload work?

Comment: With whitenoise off and `DEBUG=False` retrieving and uploading files does not work neither.